# Can you access your own private git repo from Codenvy?

Tags: codenvy

This may seem like a dumb question, but the documentation is not very clear on this, and from some of the GitHub tickets it seems like they only whitelist certain hosts, so maybe you can confirm for me:

Can I clone a Git repository from my own private host? In other words, something like:

```
git clone ssh://user@myhost/repo.git
```

from the workspace? Currently it times out when I try that.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can clone from a private repo. There are a few ways to do it depending on the target (if it's GitHub for example Codenvy has a little octocat icon that makes it a single-click to setup). The docs outline the various options:

https://codenvy.com/docs/user-guide/git-svn/index.html

But generally it comes down to setting up the SSH key pair between Codenvy and the git repo. The docs include some examples. If there are specific issues that you're having or you think you've found a bug it's best to file an issue at https://github.com/codenvy/codenvy/issues

Comment: According to this issue, you cannot just clone from anywhere: https://github.com/codenvy/codenvy/issues/1287. Perhaps I wasn't clear what I meant with a "private" repo. This is not on GitHub. It's a server I own.

Comment: I see...We do have to be careful on our public cloud as we have had users abuse the system for illegal activities. The other option for you may be to install your own Eclipse Che server - then you have total control although for the moment Che is a single identity system.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I imagine that is a risk.